# What are the outer dimensions of the adapter rings for Cokin Z/Lee filter holders

Tags: filters, lee, cokin

I was wondering if someone could tell me the outer diameter of the **adapter rings** for the Cokin Z or Lee 100mm filter holders.

I am trying to adapt a Matte Box that someone has given me, that appears to clamp onto a ring in the 95-105mm range and am wondering if the Cokin Z or Lee adapter rings will suffice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reckon my Lee ones are 99mm give or take less than half a mm.